# error while using two columns to filter results with one keyword

Tags: php, mysql

i get an error when i add another column (ReplyN) to the filter 
this is my code

```
if($keyword) {
            $filter .= "\n $syntax t.title LIKE .$db->Quote("%$keyword%") OR t.ReplyN LIKE ".$db->Quote("%$keyword%");
            $syntax = "AND";
        }
```

full code is :

```
// Setup query filter
        if($keyword) {
            $filter .= "\n $syntax t.title LIKE .$db->Quote("%$keyword%") OR t.ReplyN LIKE ".$db->Quote("%$keyword%");
            $syntax = "AND";
        }

        if($ms > 0) {
            $filter .= "\n $syntax(t.milestone = $ms)";
            $syntax = "AND";
        }
        if($status == 1) {
            $filter .= "\n $syntax(t.progress < 100)";
            $syntax = "AND";
        }
        if($status == 2) {
            $filter .= "\n $syntax(t.progress = 100)";
            $syntax = "AND";
        }
        if($priority > 0) {
            $filter .= "\n $syntax(t.priority = $priority)";
            $syntax = "AND";
        }
        if($assigned == 2) {
            $user = PFuser::GetInstance();
            $filter .= "\n $syntax (tu.user_id = ".$user->GetId()." AND tu.task_id = t.id)";
            $syntax = "AND";
        }
        if($assigned > 2) {
            $filter .= "\n $syntax (tu.user_id = ".$assigned." AND tu.task_id = t.id)";
            $syntax = "AND";
        }
        if($all) {
            $filter .= "\n $syntax(t.project IN($project))";
        }
        else {
            $filter .= "\n $syntax(t.project = '$project')";
        }
```

Comment: If you are getting an error, please at least tell us what that error is in your question.

Comment: Shoudnt your double quotes be closed at the end not after LIKE?

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your string

```
"LIKE .$db->Quote("%$keyword%") OR"
```

Should be

```
"LIKE ".$db->Quote("%$keyword%")." OR"
```